# table data filter in laravel 5.6

Tags: html, laravel-5

I have a table where I am showing all the data. Now I want to make a **filter to show specific data**. I want to execute this query "SELECT * FROM `internal_visitors` WHERE isSignIn = 1" in Laravel. But I didn't get any data.

**Controller**

```
public function index(Request $request){

    $hosts = App\Host::all();
    if($request->method('post') && $request->isSignIn!=""){
        $isSignIn  = $request->isSignIn;

        $internalVisitors =     InternalVisitor::where('isSignIn', '=', 1)->get();

        dd(internalVisitors);
    } 


    else{

        $internalVisitors = InternalVisitor::all();
    }


    return view('admin\internalVisitor', compact('hosts','internalVisitors'));
}
```

view:

```
<form action="{{route('internalVisitor')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<li>
    <button name="isSignIn" type="submit">is</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($request->method('post') && $request->isSignIn!="")
```

Replace By if `($request->isMethod('post') && $request->has('isSignIn'))`